# Get min/max value by key - different approaches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table with two columns namely ID and KEY (let key here be an integer) such as

```
ID KEY
ABC 6
DEF 1
GHI 12
```

TASK: Get the ID of the MAX key

Solution 1:

```
Select Top(1) ID
from TABLE
order by KEY desc
```

Solution 2:

```
Select ID
from TABLE 
where ID = MAX(ID)
```

**EDIT**: The query was invalid. This is what I meant:

```
Select ID
from TABLE 
where KEY = (select max(KEY) from TABLE)
```

Is one of these solutions categorically better than the other? What are the advantages/disvantages of each solution.

**EDIT**: 
Assume there is no index. 
Case 1 - large table
Case 2 - small table

Background: 
I am doing code review and I have found both solutions multiple times in different context - sometimes with indices, sometimes without, sometimes for large tables, sometimes for small.

Comment: how many records in your table? do you have index on ID column?

Comment: Does the second query even work?

Comment: No, it doesnt. I will edit the question

Comment: @Nikolas Rieble: I've corrected your new query. I've also put back the original query in the request, because otherwise the answers you already got are confusing. You may want to inform the answerers of your edit, so they might adjust their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries are different (after your edits fixing the second one).

The first necessarily returns a single row.

The second returns *all* matching rows.

The first returns a row even when `key` is NULL.

The second does not.

You should use the logic that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list..

Solution 1 will be the best. A subquery in a where clause will be less optimal.
There really are lots of design techniques to look at for performance which I am not going to go into with this answer. I found this article yesterday which gave me more perspective https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-server-storage-internals-101/

Answer (score 1):

In Solution 1, the order by clause will just sort your query result.
Query execution order:

FROM clause ON clause OUTER clause WHERE clause GROUP BY clause HAVING clause SELECT clause DISTINCT clause ORDER BY clause TOP clause

You can use the following query:

```
Select ID,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY KEY DESC) AS KeyRank
from table1
HAVING keyRank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 will work but Solution 2 will throw exception like bellow

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 22 An aggregate may not appear in the
>   WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause
>   or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer
>   reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with  query 1 ,

You cannot use query 2 because you cannot use aggregate function like that if you want to use where  clause and aggregate function  in your query you have to go with  as below :

```
Select id  from table where key in (select max(key) from test);
```

*reference only  using aggregate function and having clause*

```
Select  ID ,max(key)
   from test
   group by ID,key
   having (key) >= 12
    order by 1
```